# Paypal ProFlow Gateway API the same as Direct Advanced/Pro?

Tags: paypal, nopcommerce, payflowpro

I have a client that is using Paypal Proflow Gateway and we are upgrading there E-comm package.. the package supports Paypal Direct out of the box. I've been doing some digging and Direct & Proflow use the same documentation.. are they infact the same API?

I just want to determin if I can use the out of the box PayPal direct module, or if I need to code an all new Proflow Gateway module.

Thanks all

(FYI: the package in question is NopCommerce)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the US, PayPal Payments Pro accounts created after April 2012 include both the Direct Payments API (formerly known as Website Payments Pro, configured with a USER/PWD/SIGNATURE) as well as a native Payflow gateway account for use via the Payflow Pro API (configured with a PARTNER/VENDOR/USER/PWD)

One or the other should be used.  Payflow is preferred when available.

Comment: The account I am working with is very old (2004ish).. would I still take this opportunity to upgrade to the newer API or should write up a new module to use the older API?

Comment: Do you have a Payflow module currently?  You can generate Payflow API credentials on old accounts under Profile -> My Selling Tools -> "Request API credentials"  (or API Access -> Update) -> Payflow API.

Comment: in code (NopCommerce) I have the Direct API out of the box.. On the account, yes I have the Payflow Gateway module currently.

Comment: What do you mean you have Payflow on the (2004) account?  Is this a Payflow-only account (no PayPal involved) ?  If so, you will need to use the Payflow API.  There may be a module for NopCommerce somewhere.

Comment: They have the paypal Payflow gateway.. and they use it in connection with there merchant account.. they don't have any of the Paypal Direct services... I just noticed that the two services seem to have simpler APIs so I was wondering if they were infact the same or not..  and the only reference to payflow gateway for nop is an older package that doesn't seem to actually unzip so I can't say if it works or not :-P.

Comment: *nods* The APIs are very similar in what they can accomplish, but the Direct Payment API is only available to customers with a PayPal Payments Pro merchant account (not available on a Payflow Pro account w/o a PayPal MA attached)